# PWA app dosen't receives push notifications after app is closed

Tags: push-notification, nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, onesignal

I have implemented Onesignals web push in my PWA app made on nuxt it works fine and it receive push notification till the app is opened, but after closing the app no more notifications are received but i checked on oneSignals dashboard it shows 'Received'. (This happens in some devices, while other devices receive notifiacation even if the app is closed )